# How to design domain model with interfaces that are dependent on the model's properties

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have a domain model (see example below) that has several interfaces that are determined based upon the value of properties within the model itself.  While the code below "works" it doesn't feel right.  I am sure that there is probably a better approach, but I haven't been able to come up with one.  I would be very interested in getting feedback with some alternate approaches.

```
public interface IPickListGenerator
    {
        void Execute();
    }

public class SportsPicklistGenerator : IPickListGenerator
{
        public void Execute()
        {
            // Do something
        }
}

public class EntertainmentPicklistGenerator : IPickListGenerator
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public interface IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer
{
    void Execute();
}

public class GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer : IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class RoundQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer : IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Pool
{
    public enum PoolType
    {
        Sports,
        Entertainment
    }

    public enum DeadlineType
    {
        Game,
        Round
    }

    private IPickListGenerator mPickListGenerator = null;
    private IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer mQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = null;

    public PoolType Type { get; set; }
    public DeadlineType Deadline { get; set; }

    public IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer IsQuestionAnswerableDeterminer
    {
        get
        {
            if (mQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer == null) SetPoolSpecificInterfaces();
            return mQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer;
        }
    }

    public IPickListGenerator PickListGenerator
    {
        get
        {
            if (mPickListGenerator == null) SetPoolSpecificInterfaces();
            return mPickListGenerator;
        }
    }

    private void SetPoolSpecificInterfaces()
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case Pool.PoolType.Sports:
                mPickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator();
                break;
            case Pool.PoolType.Entertainment:
                mPickListGenerator = new EntertainmentPicklistGenerator();
                break;
        }

        switch (Deadline)
        {
            case Pool.DeadlineType.Game:
                mQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer();
                break;
            case Pool.DeadlineType.Round:
                mQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new RoundQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer();
                break;
        }
    }
}
// Example usages:
    var pool = new Pool{ Type = Pool.PoolType.Sports, Deadline = Pool.DeadLineType.Game};
    pool.IsQuestionAnswerableDeterminer.Execute();
    pool.PickListGenerator.Execute();
```

Comment: Look into the strategy and factory patterns...

Comment: Try to look into your code from the bird's eye...

Comment: I can't believe that no one considered that my code is useful. Is that really means that it is not useful to anyone? Can't say that this code is OK, because it's really obvious that there are many flaws in use cases up there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than potential logical inconsistencies (subsequently setting `Type` or `Deadline` will result in the "incorrect" value for your determiner and generator being supplied back to the user), I don't see anything wrong with the design from a larger perspective. This is very similar to the way a lot of factory patterns work: an external interface (or base class) that's implemented by multiple internal concrete classes, the correct instance of which is determined by some sort of discriminating value.

Unless the construction is expensive (and won't always be necessary), I'd suggest moving to smarter properties for `Type` and `Deadline` that set the appropriate interface implementation variables in their `set` blocks rather than loading them lazily in the other properties as you do now.

If the construction *is* expensive, I would still switch to smarter properties for `Type` and `Deadline` and clear out (and do any necessary clean up on) the values that might have been previously set.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Probably, you do not understand, that interfaces are used to extend implementation, but when author uses enums for each particular interfaces, he effectively destroys the elegancy of interface usage, so he had to rewrite Pool class again and again, and again, to support new interface implementations, when they are will come, and one time he will forget to do this. That would be a sorry story about Pete and wolfs, because in a more complex systems than that, nobody will know, why code is not working whilst it should...

Comment: @Artur: I'm fully aware of why interfaces exist and what they do. There is, however, no particular reason to think that the OP is ever going to have to support particular interface implementations (in other words, end-user types) that are outside of his control. Whether it's an enum or some other value, the idea of exposing an interface or abstract type and instantiating one particular internal implementation of that interface or abstract type based upon that value is used *all over the place* in, say, the factory pattern.

Comment: @Arnis: While it's a technical violation of Open/Closed, I wouldn't put a principle like that above ease of maintenance. Whether or not that's an important consideration is very much project dependent.

Comment: @Adam that's true. simpleness is better than complexity. but we can't really know nature of situation in this particular case. at least I can't because of little knowledge about aim of functionality.

Comment: @Adam awww... You already said that in last sentence. guess I should go to sleep. :)

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I closed you issue, phanx

Comment: @Adam Robinson, @Arnis L. : You can preserve both simpleness and elegance, keeping open/closed principle, just i did, so I hope that code will helps

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to remove the dependencies from your code. Excessiveness from your code exists is in 2 ways:

- you have an excessive code (interfaces)
- you have an excessive constraints (enums)

Finally, I've got this, in dialog with Adam, which eliminates exception throws, the need of two switch statement, two enumerations, whilst preserving pool closures and elimination possible errors in code. For each switch statement (each interface implementation pair), you have to implement its own static method instantiating Pool class properly:

```
public interface IPool
{
    void Execute();
}

public class Pool : IPool
{
    private Pool() { }

    public IPickListGenerator PickListGenerator { set; private get; }
    public IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer { set; private get; }

    public static IPool GetSportsGame() 
    {
        return new Pool
        {
            PickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator(),
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer()
        };
    }
    public static IPool GetSportsEntertainment() 
    {
        return new Pool
        {
            PickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator(),
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new EntertainmentPicklistGenerator()
        };
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer.Execute();
        PickListGenerator.Execute();
    }
}
```

--- History of that post, leading to this solution:

You can improve your code by simplifying the code, because in your implementation, Pool class is limited to enumerations, and if so, the Pool class is not extensible. You probably will have to rewrite SetPoolSpecificInterfaces() again and again, when new requirements and interface implementation comes into view. So the weakest point of the current design is that particular SetPoolSpecificInterfaces() method and if so, not extensible Pool class.

If that is what you required, than interfaces is not really needed. In other case, you will not be dependent upon number of interface implementations (which is actually fixed by the corresponding enum) so, it probably can be be simplified to following code (i fixed the issues), removing these constraints:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Example usages:
            var pool = new Pool
            {
                PickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator(),
                IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer()
            };
            pool.ExecuteIsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer();
            pool.ExecutePickListGenerator();
        }
    }

    public class Pool
    {
        public IPickListGenerator PickListGenerator { set; private get; }
        public IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer { set; private get; }

        public void ExecuteIsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer()
        {
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer.Execute();
        }

        public void ExecutePickListGenerator()
        {
            PickListGenerator.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

You probably can stop here, but what if you will always call ExecuteIsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer() before ExecutePickListGenerator() call? then you can refacor code as follows:

```
    public class Pool
    {
        public IPickListGenerator PickListGenerator { set; private get; }
        public IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer 
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer { set; private get; }

        public void Execute()
        {
            // improvements, seen by Arnis
            if (IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer == null)
            {
                thrown new ArgumentException("IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer");
            }
            if (PickListGenerator == null)
            {
                thrown new ArgumentException("PickListGenerator");
            }
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer.Execute();
            PickListGenerator.Execute();
        }
    }
```

If so, you can write something looks like this:

```
var pool = new Pool
{
    PickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator(),
    IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer()
};
pool.Execute();

// reuse the same class logic in Pool class in Execute method
pool.PickListGenerator = new GamePickListGenerator();
pool.Execute();

// reuse the same class logic in Pool class in Execute method
pool.IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new RoundQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer();
pool.Execute();
```

As @Adam Robinson said, it changes some logic of Pool (to fix this you can use close Pool implementation), so you can fix it in this way, introducing new interface, IPool, adding private constructor to Pool class and static logic instantiation, that will eliminate the need of a swith statement completely:

```
public interface IPool
{
    void Execute();
}

public class Pool : IPool
{
    private Pool() { }

    public IPickListGenerator PickListGenerator { set; private get; }
    public IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer { set; private get; }

    public static IPool GetSportsGame() 
    {
        return new Pool
        {
            PickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator(),
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer()
        };
    }
    public static IPool GetSportsEntertainment() 
    {
        return new Pool
        {
            PickListGenerator = new SportsPicklistGenerator(),
            IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer = new EntertainmentPicklistGenerator()
        };
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        IsQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer.Execute();
        PickListGenerator.Execute();
    }
}
```

---

This was edited by Arnis:

```
public class Pool{
  private readonly IPickListGenerator _generator;
  private readonly IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer _determiner;
  public Pool(IPickListGenerator generator, 
    IQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer determiner){

    if(determiner==null||generator==null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
    _generator=generator;
    _determiner=determiner;
  }

  public void Execute(){
    _determiner.Execute();
    _generator.Execute();
  }
}

var generator=new SportsPicklistGenerator();
var determiner=new GameQuestionIsAnswerableDeterminer();
var pool = new Pool(generator, determiner);
pool.Execute();
```

Comment: My assumption was that those were placeholder methods and that the actual implementations were different, since the details of the interface weren't relevant to the question.

Comment: The implementations are different, they are not duplicates.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: You were right, and i fixed issued, had been refactored the code, and it seems to me, that Pool class is nothing but simply a placeholder for a pair of interfaces (their implementations), isn't it?

Comment: You should favor constructor injection over setter injection. Seems to me that pool can't function w/o pick list generator so it's a good idea to restrict creation of pool w/o pick list generator. Will modify Your answer to show exactly what I mean. Feel free to roll back if You want to.

Comment: @Mike if You told us what exactly pool, pick list generator and "question is answerable" determiners do, maybe we could come up with more helpful ideas. What is the ultimate goal for each of those?

Comment: This answer changes the substance of the OP's class. In his version, the instantiation and selection of the particular interface implementations were both done internally. This version requires that the consumer of this class specify the implementation himself, which might not be feasible, desirable, or even possible.

Comment: @Arnis L.: Agreed ;) On one hand, by favoring a construction logic to properties logic, you will get a time synchronization exchanged to additional flexibility of class instance (time-independent instantiation of a particular interfaces), but it is OK, if this is a desired exchange. On the other hand, you are right, i have forgotten checking for a null-value logic ;)

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Pool class is just a placholder for behavioral logic using interfaces, not more. Otherwise interfaces are not required and are excessive in this situation, where you uses it internally. If so the interfaces and their implementations must be declared internal and used in Pool class internally also.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I fixed the code an included improvements in code, which eliminates the need of switch statement completely, arguing your issue

Comment: @Artur, @Arnis: I think you guys have misunderstood the intent of my example.  The "Pool" class in reality contains much more in the way of properties and methods beyond the two enums and interfaces that are shown in the example.  The two interfaces are dependent on different property values and are called at completely different points in time.  What the two interfaces actually do is not relevant to my original question, which is really focused on whether this design coul be improved upon.